# How to have an object call a method when another object's attribute changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set up a system where a method of one object is called whenever an attribute of a different object is modified, with the new value as an argument to the method.  How would I accomplish something like that?

Edit:  Code sample/clarification:

My code looks something like this:

```
class SharedAttribute(object):  #I use this as a container class to share attributes between multiple objects
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **shared_attributes:
        for (key, value) in shared_attributes:
            if isinstance(value, SharedAttribute):
                setattr(self, key, value)

            else:
                setattr(self, key, SharedAttribute(value))

class MyObject(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        BaseObject.__init__(self, value1, value2)

    def on_value_changed(self, new_value):
        #Do something here

    def incrementValue(self):
        self.value1.value += 1
```

And then it would be implemented like:

```
a = MyObject(value1 = 1)
b = MyObject(value1 = MyObject.value1)  #a and b are storing references to the same attribute, so when one changes it, it's changed for the other one too.
```

I want to set it up so if I were to call `a.incrementValue()`, `b.on_value_changed` would be called, with the `SharedAttribute`'s new value as an argument.  Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: That doesn't sound remotely like a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @property is for calling a method within the same object, I want to call a method within a different object

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a manager style attribute similar to how Django uses `ModelManager`'s (`model.objects` for example):

```
class Foo(object):
    def method_to_call(self, new_val):
        print('Hello from manager. Doing stuff with {}'.format(new_val))


class Bar(object):
    manager = Foo()

    def __init__(self, your_attr):
        self.your_attr = your_attr

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        if key == 'your_attr':
            self.manager.method_to_call(val)
        super(Bar, self).__setattr__(key, val)
```

And to use it:

```
>>> bar = Bar('some value')
Hello from manager. Doing stuff with some value
>>> bar.your_attr = 'A new value'
Hello from manager. Doing stuff with A new value
```

If you want use a specific instance of `Foo` to manage a specific instance of `Bar` you can modify `__init__()` to take an instance of `Foo` and use that. Since we are making a `super()` call here it's important to keep track of your inheritance. I don't know how your app is setup but if you are using multiple inheritance things can get weird.

Comment: I'm not sure how well this would work for my specific case.  `Bar` is actually created by the superclass of `Foo`, so the information about what method to call has to be passed as arguments to `Foo`'s `__init__`, and then from there to `Foo`'s superclass's `__init__`, and from there to the respective `Bar`s (Each `Bar` is just storing a single attribute, so there will be a bunch).  I feel like that could get pretty complicated pretty quickly if `Foo` has a bunch of methods, each called by a different `Bar`

Comment: That's a pretty different question then what you originally asked. You are going to have post a code sample so we can see what your code is doing. From your description it sounds like there might be a design issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're being specific about which attributes are being updated and you have special knowledge of those attributes -- IOW you don't need to know whenever *every* attribute of some object changes -- then you probably just want some kind of observer pattern by way of properties.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        whatever_else_you_wanted_to_happen()
```

Otherwise if you're trying to get generic (which you probably don't want) then you end up wrapping a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, which has its own pros and cons.

```
class B(object):
    pass

def wrapper(objmethod):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs)
        some_other_thing_you_wanted_to_happen()
        return objmethod(*args, **kwargs)
    return _inner

B.__setattr__ = wrapper(B.__setattr__)
```

That's really sort of JavaScript-y prototype-y though, and so people that like Python looking like Python will probably get their cooking spoons out and whack you with them.

I think ultimately if you want to do this you'll want to just stick to decorators. The attribute accessors aren't exposed in a way that you can just 'hook in' without writing a getter/setter so you'll almost certainly want properties and decorators anyway.